# Custom notification size on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, mobile-device-management

I would like to receive customized notifications from any specific app on my iPhone so that I can never ignore it because they are super important.

One solution I thought of is to show notification as a popup on the screen while using the iPhone or show it large size when phone is locked. I'm not sure how to implement it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

PS: I have also supervised my iPhone through MDM.

Answer (score 1):

Not resizing, but you can set the banner to be permanent/ persistent instead of temporary in Notification Settings.

Comment: Okay, any ideas on how I can show notifications as a custom popup while using phone?

Comment: I am not aware of modifications in notifications' appearances.